# Rails plugin: undefined method 'mattr_accessor' for Sentry:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rake

I'm looking at an existing Rails project and trying to see what rake tasks exist by running `rake -T`. However, when I run that I get:

```
(in /var/www/project)
rake aborted!
undefined method `mattr_accessor' for Sentry:Module
/var/www/project/Rakefile:10
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`vendor/plugins/sentry/tasks/sentry.rake` has nothing called `mattr_accessor` in it. What is this error message referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this resolved itself while I was working on other issues. I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but I believe it had to do with outdated/conflicting versions of plugins and gems.

Answer (score 0):

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Did you try running the rake command with the --trace option?